# How to track committed offset with Spark job for kafka batch

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spark-structured-streaming

I have a use case where i am writing to a Kafka topic in batches using spark job (no streaming).Initially i pump-in suppose 10 records to Kafka topic and run the spark job which does some processing and finally write to another Kafka topic.
Next time when i push another 5 records and run the spark job, my requirement is to start processing these 5 records only not from starting offset. I need to maintain the committed offset so that spark job should run on next offset position and do the processing.
Here is code from kafka side to fetch the offset:

```
private static List<TopicPartition> getPartitions(KafkaConsumer consumer, String topic) {
        List<PartitionInfo> partitionInfoList = consumer.partitionsFor(topic);
        return partitionInfoList.stream().map(x -> new TopicPartition(topic, x.partition())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void getOffSet(KafkaConsumer consumer) {
        
        List<TopicPartition> topicPartitions = getPartitions(consumer, topic);
        
        consumer.assign(topicPartitions);
        consumer.seekToBeginning(topicPartitions);

        topicPartitions.forEach(x -> {
            System.out.println("Partition-> " + x + " startingOffSet-> " + consumer.position(x));
        });
        consumer.assign(topicPartitions);
        consumer.seekToEnd(topicPartitions);
        topicPartitions.forEach(x -> {
            System.out.println("Partition-> " + x + " endingOffSet-> " + consumer.position(x));
        });
        
        topicPartitions.forEach(x -> {
            consumer.poll(1000) ;
            OffsetAndMetadata offsetAndMetadata = consumer.committed(x);
            long position = consumer.position(x);
            System.out.printf("Committed: %s, current position %s%n", offsetAndMetadata == null ? null : offsetAndMetadata
                    .offset(), position);
        });
    }
```

Below code is for spark to load the messages from topic which is not working :

```
 Dataset<Row> kafkaDataset = session.read().format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                .option("subscribe", topic)
                .option("group.id", "test-consumer-group")
                .option("startingOffsets","{\"Topic1\":{\"0\":2}}")
                .option("endingOffsets", "{\"Topic1\":{\"0\":3}}")
                .option("enable.auto.commit","true")
                .load();
```

After above code executes i am again trying to get the offset by calling

```
getoffset(consumer)
```

from the topic which always reads from 0 offset and committed offset fetched initially keeps on increasing. I am new to kafka and still figuring out how to handle such scenarion.Please help here.

Initially i had 10 records in my topic, i published another 2 records and here is the o/p:
Output post getoffset method executes :

> Partition-> Topic00-0 startingOffSet-> 0 Partition->
> Topic00-0 endingOffSet-> 12 Committed: 12, current position
> 12

Output post spark code executes for loading messages.

> Partition-> Topic00-0 startingOffSet-> 0 Partition->
> Topic00-0 endingOffSet-> 12 Committed: 12, current position
> 12

I see no diff and . Please take a look and suggest resolution for this sceanario.

Comment: You should be using `option("kafka.group.id"` and ideally remove the starting and ending offsets options. Then offsets are automatically handled by Spark and Kafka across restarts

Comment: @OneCricketeer first of all kafka.group.id is not valid spark option for kafka and even after i remove offset option from spark read code, i get same offset reading post n pre processing of records.have updated output in my ask.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't try it. Yes, it is an option. From Spark docs, says `group.id` **cannot be set**. Then says "You can ... set **`“kafka.group.id”`**  to force Spark to use a special group id, however, please read warnings for this option and use it with caution."

Comment: i get this error  Kafka option 'group.id' is not supported as user-specified consumer groups is not used to track offsets if i use kafka.group.id

Comment: What Spark version are you using? You will need to upgrade to Spark 3 to use that option

Comment: i am using 2.4.0 currently, challenge for me is i cannot upgrade the spark version

Comment: In that case, [documentation still says `group.id` cannot be set. Spark automatically creates one. Similarly `enable.auto.commit` cannot be set.](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#kafka-specific-configurations) You'll need another place to store and fetch offsets, such as Zookeeper. Otherwise, it'll always use the same start/end that you've hard-coded